# __declspec (dllexport) custom type variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, dllimport, dllexport

I'm working on a Visual Studio solution with multiple projects (Visual Studio 2013). One project is for generating a `.dll` file, other projects use that `.dll` file and generate `.exe` files. When I export a standard type variable everything works fine. But in case if I want to use my custom defined type I get an compilation error. Here is an example

```
// Dll.cpp
#define DllExport __declspec (dllexport)
DllExport int maxPackSize = 20;
// my custom type
struct DllExport Header
{
    int m_data;    // some data
};
DllExport Header qHead = { 100 };


// Exe.cpp
#define DllImport __declspec (dllimport)
DllImport extern int packetSize;    // OK

struct DllImport Header;
DllImport extern Header qHead;      // leads to an error
```

When I use `qHead` in my `Exe.cpp` I get a compilation error on that line. Error is like

> error C2027: use of undefined type 'Header'

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you get is a compiler error (not a linker error!).
You need to define `Header` prior to its first use.

You could move `struct DllExport Header { ... };` to a separate header file (e.g. `Dll.h`) and then `#include "Dll.h"` in `Exe.cpp`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to export your custom type in a header, so that your .exe can see the type. For example,

Dll.h

```
#ifdef EXPORT_SYMBOLS
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

struct DLL_EXPORT Header
{
   int m_data;
};
```

Exe.cpp

```
#include "Dll.h"
Header qHead;
```

You need to add `EXPORT_SYMBOLS` to the Dll's preprocessor flags so that the correct __declspec macro is switched.

Comment: To add to this, Visual Studio automatically adds libname_EXPORTS define when building libname project. You can use it with #ifdef to select right value for DLL_EXPORT.